# systemctl hibernate AND reboot?

Tags: linux, systemd, grub2

I have two Linux images on different volumes and a /boot partition that is separate from both of them. I want my users to be able to hibernate their 'desktop Linux OS' at night, rebooting into the 'render farm Linux OS'.

In the morning, the 'render farm OS' will shut down and boot the system back into the hibernated desktop Linux session.

I figure I can enable this with a script that modifies the grub2 config and then runs `systemctl hibernate`, which gets me most of the way there, but really I need the system to not just hibernate the running OS; I need it to hibernate the running OS and then reboot.

There doesn't *seem* to be any provision for systemctl to both hibernate and then reboot. It can do either one or the other.

How can I make this work?

Comment: Is there a way to make this only affect the next boot? I have peeked at the systemd code and it seems they are doing slightly more than just writing these strings... (Maybe this should be a separate question)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reconfigure the existing 'hibernate' mode to reboot instead of powering off in `/etc/systemd/sleep.conf`:

```
[Sleep]
HibernateMode=reboot
```

Or you can do the same to the 'hybrid-sleep' mode (which is hibernate + suspend):

```
[Sleep]
HybridSleepMode=reboot
```

The value directly corresponds to text that systemd will write to `/sys/power/disk`.

---

Background: systemd doesn't actually perform hibernation, it just tells the kernel to do so:

1. systemd writes the desired post-hibernation mode ("platform" for S4 shutdown, "suspend" for hybrid sleep, or "reboot" for your customization) to the file `/sys/power/disk`.
2. systemd writes the hibernation command "disk" to the file `/sys/power/state`.
3. The kernel does the rest, and doesn't return back to systemd until the computer has woken up.

Comment: Just to clarify - the `/etc/systemd/sleep.conf` file did not yet exist on my CentOS7 system, but I created it with the advised contents and it worked correctly.

Big thanks to @grawity for a fast & accurate response!